# Where to include ignoreWindowOnLoad settings on Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have charts and data on my webpage and google.charts.setOnLoadCallback() function causing all the charts load after everything is loaded. I would like to load everything at once. I heard about ignoreWindowOnLoad setting but not sure how to enable it:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/JJQ90OQrLbM

Comment: Please provide more details, with snippet of code.

Comment: Code is similar to the below example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_google_pie_chart.     But, I have lot of other tables and hence the graph is loaded after tables are loaded and displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include in the `load` statement,
and you can include the `callback` as well...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawCharts,
  packages: ['corechart'],
  ignoreWindowOnLoad: true
}
```